# Trying to remove autolevel from G-code - offset from bed not correct

Tags: marlin, g-code, firmware, lulzbot

I’ve been having all kinds of trouble with really every part of the print procedure on my Lulzbot Mini 2 that comes before the actual extrusion starts. I think I can get around 90 % of my issues if I just ran a level X axis at the start then input a manual Z calibration level.

I tried stripping out the nozzle wipe and autolevel commands from the beginning of the G-code but then the printer started the job about a centimeter above the bed.

Does anyone know how I can safely correct my Z-offset?

I'm currently using Lulzbot Cura but am planning to switch to Ultimaker Cura once I've got test prints going again.

Edit:

There is a z-offset that can be set using the physical printer UI but I suspect this isn't the setting I should be trying to alter as theoretically it should be pretty close to right since my vanilla Lulzbot Cura gcodes used to work and I haven't changed that value. Am I wrong on this?

Comment: Send `M851 Z0` to reset the Z-offset, but I kinda get the feeling this isn't the offset you mean, or do you? Note to use `M500` to store.

Comment: I can give that a shot, thanks! TBH I'm so out of my depth here I don't know what exactly I'm looking for and I dont want to setup a scenario where I accidentally gouge my print surface.

I just know that the extruder started printing waaaay to high after my change.

Comment: I think you are "asking for a solution" (you think that the auto levelling is your problem),  while you should address the original problem and describe what's wrong with the prints.

Comment: The original problems are many which is why I skirted around explaining them. I have a slight issue that causes my Y belt to skip on fast travels, my X bar doesn't stay level between prints, and the autolevel probe (which is the nozzle in the case of this printer) doesn't seem to be getting electronic contact with the leveling washers despite both appearing to be clean. I think the simpler solution for me at this point would be to live with all those issues but I can't get to the print step because the autolevel fails repeatedly until the printer gives up and halts.